# https doesn't work but http works fine on ( aws beanstalk , route 53 ) ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, aws-acm

Https dont work even i followed the tutorial

http://go-dance.fr/ work fine

http://sbk.go-dance.fr/ work fine

**but  https://go-dance.fr/ doesn't work fine** ,  it give the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Route 53 Dashboard
[image]

[image]

[image]

I changed the port to 433 (ont http and https ) but still not working
[image]

Comment: Did you change the ports? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates and HTTPS work on port **443**, not port 80. So you have to change your setup to use that port.